# Recovering Time Shift Using DFT of Translated Square Pulse?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

As an exercise, I attempted to manually translate a pulse $n_0$ steps to the right and recover the translation using the [time-shift property](http://ocw.usu.edu/Electrical_and_Computer_Engineering/Signals_and_Systems/5_6node6.html). The problem I'm encountering is that the phase unwrapping of the fft of the translated pulse is not a straight line like it should be, despite that the theoretical and manually translated pulses appear to be exactly the same. I've written a very simple script to illustrate this. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? This is important because in reality, I won't have $n_0$.

[EDIT]

Here is the math showing how to recover the translation.

$$y(t) = x(t-t_0) = x(t)*h(t)$$
$$Y(\omega) = X(\omega)H(\omega)$$
By the time shift property:
$$H(\omega) = e^{-j\omega t_0}$$
$$e^{-j\omega t_0} = Y(\omega)/X(\omega)$$
$$t_0 = -ang(H(\omega))/w$$

```
from numpy import *
from scipy import *

N = 1000
n0 = 200

pulse =  zeros(N)
pulset = zeros(N)
pulse[100:200] = 1
pulset[100+n0:200+n0] = 1 # t0 = 100

f = arange(0, 1, 1./N)
w = 2*pi*f

X = fft(pulse)
Y1 = fft(pulset)
Y2 = exp(-1j*w*n0)*X # theoretical transformation

plot(Y1) # Y1 and Y2 look the same
plot(Y2)
print(sum([abs(Y1[i] - Y2[i]) for i in range(0, len(Y1))])) # 1.12701544921e-10

figure()

t1 = -unwrap(angle(Y1/X))/w
t2 = -unwrap(angle(Y2/X))/w

plot(t1)
plot(t2)

figure()

plot(unwrap(angle(Y1/X)))
plot(unwrap(angle(Y2/X)))
```

[EDIT2]
I posted pictures of the super imposed FFTS of Y1 and Y2, unwrapped phase and calculated time shift.

[EDIT3]
Same pictures (minus the FFTs) but with multipling by conj(X) instead of dividing by X

[EDIT4]

So after looking at MATLAB code (in comments) I looked into the phase unwrapping and indeed after I changed the `discont` parameter to 5, the phase unwrapped more correctly meaning it was unwrapping where it should not have (second last picture) but looking at the calculated time shift (last picture) there were still spikes. I then looked at the super imposed wrapped phase (third last picture - I zoomed in) and indeed they were different, unlike in MATLAB where they are exactly the same. It is worth noting that I am using 32 bit python and I ran the MATLAB code in 64 bit MATLAB although I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

[image: Super imposed FFTs]

[image: Super imposed unwrapped phases]

[image: Super imposed calculated time shifts]

[image: Super imposed unwrapped phase - multiplied by conj(X) instead of division by X]

[image: Super imposed calculated time shift - multiplied by conj(X)]

[image: Superimposed wrapped phase of Y1 and Y2. notice they are not the same]

[image: Super imposed Unwrapped phase after increasing discont parameter to 5]

[image: Super imposed calculated time shift]

Comment: Why are you dividing by `X` when calculating `t1` and `t2`? Even if there is good reason for it, won't you end up dividing some of the samples by zero?

Comment: You do and you do get errors but just ignore them. I'll update with the derivation.

Comment: I'm not exactly following. Plotting them they look the same and printing the sum of the differences is negligibly small. Theoretically they should be the same by the time shift property. Yet, clearly they are different. I agree `X` and `Y1` are sinc functions but why is `Y2` different?

Comment: Doh. I missed the `*X` at the end. Please disregard that last comment.

Comment: You'll have to post a picture of what you are seeing. I just wrote up the equivalent of your code in matlab and I don't see any appreciable differences. Perhaps python is handling the divide by zero cases differently. As an aside, you might get better defined results using `angle(Y * conj(X))` rather than dividing. That way, you avoid zeros in the denominator.

Comment: I've posted the pictures. I wrote explanations but I can't see them. I'm not sure how it works. Can you see?

Comment: I multiplied by conj(X) and the results look slightly better but it stays around 150 instead of going to 200 and then dropping out.

Comment: Do they match if you don't divide by `w`? I'm getting the expected results in matlab, so maybe it's just a coding problem.

Comment: I'll try to write equivalent matlab code. Can you post yours somewhere?

Comment: See [here](http://pastebin.com/Y6Zrh4yg).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24738/discussion-between-user2316667-and-anonsubmitter85).

Comment: Try zeropadding the fft. That will decrease the sample spacing and should help with the phase unwrapping.

Comment: I increased N to 10000 and still no better results. Also, 64-bit python did not help. The wrapped phase are still slightly different but only at select multiples of 10, e.g. 20, 40, 80, 100, 120, 160...

Comment: I guess you'll have to look into pythons unwrapping algorithm. There should be a parameter that controls how close the phase must be to $\pm \pi$ before it unwraps. Perhaps there is a python forum where this has been brought up.

Comment: Nope, its not the unwrapping. Its definitely the fft. Of course it unwraps differently if the fft is different. Anyway, I'll leave this question open unless you want to write an answer with a link to your matlab code and something along the lines of 'its python's problem.'